# Checar alguns valores de array dentro de outra array

Tags: php

Preciso testar se uma array possui alguns valores que são obrigatórios comparando dentro de outra array, atualmente eu conto os valores obrigatórios, abro um loop, e checo se os valores checados foram na mesma quantidade:

```
    private function validate_required($data, $required) {
        $c = count($required);
        $a = 0;
        foreach ($data as $key) {
            if (in_array($key, $required)) {
                $a += 1;
            }
        }
        if ($a != $c) {
            throw new \Exception('O elemento {elemento} não possui todos os atributos obrigatórios', 'ex0893');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

> Qual seria uma forma mais natural de fazer esse teste ?

**OBS**:

Não são todos os valores da primeira array que são obrigatórios na segunda.

As array são unidimensionais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro a utilização da função [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) que lhe dá a intereseção de dois arrays. Para o caso em questão se a interseção resultar no array de entrada então todos os elementos de `$required` existem em `$data`:

```
private function validate_required($data, $required) {
    $inBoth = array_intersect($data, $required);
    if (count($inBoth) !== $c) {
        throw new \Exception('O elemento {elemento} não possui todos os atributos obrigatórios');
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/y4YAcC)

Não seria melhor retornar falso também quando não é valido ? É estranho um método que retorna booleano apenas poder retornar `true` e nunca `false`. O código até ficaria bem mais simples:

```
private function validate_required($data, $required) {
    $inBoth = array_intersect($data, $required);
    return count($inBoth) === $c;
}
```

Para além disso também evitaria ter de chamar o método dentro de um `try catch` pois já não lançaria exceção.

Tem também [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) se pretender calcular a intereseção apenas com base na chave, assumindo que cada elemento do array tem chave e valor.

Comment: Não sabia dessa função, uma solução bem melhor, só não posso dropar um boleano pq preciso de um tratamento preciso desse false, o codigo ta mto encapsulado ai vai ser complicado tratar as exceptions com o false onde ela é chamada, mas solucionado!  obg